# WCF Service: transferMode: StreamingResponse is not working

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I'm trying to create a streaming WCF service. I have created a service that I believe should support streamed responses (as a WCF Service Application project in VS) and a client that is just a Console Application project where I have added the service as a service reference. The code works when I set the transfer mode in the client to Buffered, but if I change it to StreamedResponse I get a Stream that only has about 1500 bytes of data instead of the 33k I get when I use the buffered transfer mode.

Here are the vital parts of my code:

Interface

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.Stream
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.Samples.Stream")]
    public interface IStreamingSample
    {
        [OperationContract]
        System.IO.Stream GetStream(string data);
    }
}
```

The class that implements the interface

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.Stream
{
    public class StreamingService : IStreamingSample
    {
        public System.IO.Stream GetStream(string data)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream imageFile = File.OpenRead("e:/image.jpg");
                return imageFile;
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Web.config in service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.Samples.Stream.StreamingService">
        <endpoint address="ep1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Microsoft.Samples.Stream.IStreamingSample"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" transferMode="StreamedResponse" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

app.config in client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IStreamingSample" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="StreamedResponse"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:56881/StreamingService.svc/ep1"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IStreamingSample"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IStreamingSample" name="BasicHttpBinding_IStreamingSample" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does File.OpenRead() give you a Stream with position reset to zero? If not, SetPosition=0 before returning it;

Comment: Yes, the position is set to zero.